# How to redirect Dynamic DNS to a specific local ip address?

Tags: networking, router, lan, dynamic-dns

I'm trying to remotely access a specific computer from my LAN on which i'd like to run a webserver.
My network router is a [Pirelli A226G router](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/36559275/User-Manual-Pirelli-DRG-A226G).
I've set up a Dynamic dns account, and it works: if i type the address i land on... the router admin login screen!

But i tried setting up port forwarding or even a DMZ zone for the specific local computer that should serve web pages. (192.168.1.10). All that fails: i still land on the router login screen. What puzzles me is i suppose i should be able to tell the router "if you get a request from no-ip.org, redirect the requests to 192.168.1.10". but i can't find anywhere an interface that asks that.

Answer (score 2):

I can see why that manual isn't very helpful... nothing about port forwarding, nothing about turning off Remote Management.  Remote Management is what you are running up against right now, since most home routers by default use port 80 to allow remote management access.

One solution is to use another port for your home server, like 8080 for example.  Then, simply forward port 8080 to that internal IP address, and make sure that when you want to view the web server externally, you append :8080 to the end of the Dynamic DNS account address.  IE if you had `http://server.mine.nu` as an address, use `http://server.mine.nu:8080`.  Of course, depending on what software you are using to host the server, you would have a few configuration files to alter, to switch from using port 80 to using port 8080.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried disabling remote access, and also have found where to set up the Port Forwarding rules, but to no avail.